# .Net Publishing apps for x64, on a arm64 machine

Tags: .net, maui

I've been trying to publish my .net maui application (sideloaded MSI), such that it would run on a Windows x64 machine. My development machine is a MacBook Pro (m3 chip), but I'm running a windows 11 VM (using parallels) - which (I believe) creates an arm64 environment.

I've tried seemingly every permutation of configuration, but nothing seems to work.

I'm wondering whether dot net supports publishing in this direction (create x64 arch application, from an arm64 machine)? If so, does anyone have any examples they could help point me to?

Comment: what's the specific problem When the MAUI project runs on the windows?